# Update model from database erases all customizations to SSDL file EF4

Tags: database, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, entity-framework-4

I've made some changes to the SSDL inside the .edmx mainly for custom stored procs but whenever I do an update model from database it erases all my customization's, is there a workaround or a setting that would make it not erase my changes? example:
I'll put this inside the ssdl

```
  <Function Name="InsertUpdateStoredProc" IsComposable="false">
    <CommandText>
      EXEC TWO.dbo.InsertUpdateProduct
      @Address = @Code,
      @CustomerNumber = @CustomerNumber,
      @EquipmentID = @EquipmentID,
      @ManufacturerID = @ManufacturerID,
      @EquipmentType = @EquipmentType,

    </CommandText>
```

Then once I do an update it's overwritten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are obliged to delete your model and than create again